# Select all descendants from a container

Tags: jquery

Just a little precision: when I want to select all descendants from a container, do the two following declarations below have the same effect?

```
(1)    $('#container *').css('pointer-events','none')
```

and

```
(2)    $('#container').find('*').css('pointer-events','none')
```

Moreover, if I just want the first level of children (with solution `(1)`), can I do the following?

```
$('#container > *').css('pointer-events','none')
```

Comment: `$('#container *')`  typo with the missing end quote.

Comment: Also don't do `$('#container > *')`, rather do `$('#container').children()`

Comment: Have you tested any of your options? what have you found?

Comment: @Taplar sorry for this stupid typo. thanks for your advice. So the solution 1) is not valid unlike the solution 2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just a little precision : when I want to select all descendants from a
>   container

If you really want to **select all descendants** ..

I suggest you use `.find()`

`.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements grandchildren.

If you want to select **single level of the DOM tree**

you can use     `.children()`

`.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree

For more info please see this link ..

https://api.jquery.com/children/